# Dynamically change nth-child number

Tags: javascript, css

```
 ngx-datatable > div > datatable-body > datatable-selection:hover > datatable-scroller > datatable-row-wrapper:nth-child(n) > datatable-body-row > div.datatable-row-center.datatable-row-group > datatable-body-cell:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #E9F1FA !important;
  }
```

This is my long selector. I am trying to highlight the entire column based on the user hovering over an item on a column. This works great, except that it only highlights whatever nth-child I am using on the last `datatable-body-cell:nth-child(1)` I can change it to any number and it works, but it isn't dynamic. I want it to only select the column that is being hovered over. I've tried `datatable-body-cell:nth-child(n):hover` and `datatable-body-cell:hover` and a lot of different varieties but it either highlights the whole table, or nothing at all, unless I specify the nth-child. 
Is there a way I can dynamically change the nth-child based on the what child the user is hovering over (with CSS or Javascript)?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to get the column and set its style it is being hovered over on `mouseenter` and reset it back to normal on `mouseleave`.

```
var n = 1;//the number
document.querySelector('ngx-datatable > div > datatable-body > datatable-selection:hover > datatable-scroller > datatable-row-wrapper:nth-child('+n+') > datatable-body-row > div.datatable-row-center.datatable-row-group > datatable-body-cell:nth-child(1)').style.setProperty('background-color', '#E9F1FA', 'important');
```

Demo:

```js
var children = document.querySelectorAll('div.child');
Array.prototype.slice.call(children).forEach(function(child){
var n = child.parentNode.getAttribute('data-num');
var parent = document.querySelector('div.table>div:nth-child('+n+')');
  child.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
    parent.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
    child.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
    var n = +this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-num');
    parent.style.backgroundColor = "";
    this.style.backgroundColor = "";
  });
});
```

```css
.table{
 height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
.column{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  margin: 5px;
}
.child{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div class="column" data-num="1">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
</div>
<div class="column" data-num="2">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
</div>
<div class="column" data-num="3">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would set the class attribute instead of the style attribute, e.g. `document.querySelector(myLongSelector).classList.add('highlight')`